# How to enter a value like `x/y` for `grid-row` or `grid-column` properties in Less without being compiled as calculated?

Tags: css, less

I have this code:

```
.grid__element--1 {
  background-color: orange;
  -ms-grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
}
```

Obviously, this will be compiled to CSS as:

```
.grid__element--1 {
  background-color: orange;
  -ms-grid-row: 0.33333333; // need to be 1/3
  grid-row: 0.33333333; // need to be 1/3
}
```

Is there any way entering a value in Less for `grid-row` to be compiled correctly to `1/3`?

Comment: [The documentation mentions using `e("1/3")`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions-e) to escape things. I've also see `~"1/3"` used, as in [Escape syntax for CSS selectors in LESS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8290104)

Comment: Thanks.."String escaping" what I had to use in my search :) ..Thanks @HereticMonkey